How to not violate Open/Closed Principle when checking for type is needed
I am writing a back-end for a program that manages surveys in TypeScript but don't know how to design my Survey and SurveyRepository class without violating the Open/Closed Principle (OCP)
My survey class looks like this
class Survey {
    private readonly metadata: SurveyMetadata
    private readonly options: SurveyOptions
    private title: string
    private description: string
    private readonly questions: Question[]

//getter setter
}

class Question {

    private readonly metadata: QuestionMetadata
    private required: boolean
    private question: string

}

Now I have a class for every question type
class TextQuestion extends Question {
    //just a super call

}

class ChoiceQuestion extends Question {

    private answerOptions: AnswerOptions
    private isMultiple: boolean
 
}

Now to store my data in the database I wrote a repository class
class SurveyRepository extends IRepositroy {

    public insert(survey: Survey): number

}

Now if I want to insert a survey into a database I also need to store the questions for that I need to know the type of the question and the only way I know to do this is like this:
for(const question of questions){
   
   switch(instanceof question){
    
    case TextQuestion:
        //code to store text question
        break;
    case ChoiceQuestion:
        //code to store choice question
        break;
    }
}

But this violates the OCP.
Solutions I thought of:
Make a repository for every question type would be an option but that way the survey repository wouldn't make any sense
I read about the visitor pattern would that work in this case?
EDIT:
After more research i found this question on stackoverflow but not answerd Stack Overflow
The first solution I came up with is adding a type field to the base question and injecting a map that maps question type to the right question repository, but this approach has 1 flaw: how do I select, and if I use this solution, I will have the same problem later on the client or controller.
The second solution would be to make only one question class that holds all
The problem with this is that the questions have different properties, so I would have  a lot of nulls, and if I wanted to add a new type, I would need to change the question class every time, so same problem.
The third solution I thought of would be to not inherit from question but use an instance of question in every subtype, but how do I store the question objects in the survey class?

How exactly does this violate the OCP? Just asking because I'm not too familiar with the principle.

If I understood correctly, you're doing model related logic in the repository. That logic should be handled by the model itself. If you're not using fat models, then you should have a layer which converts your models to/from DB-friendly format. There are so many ways to achieve this. Just search for TypeScript ORM.

What do you mean with "you're doing model related logic in the repository"

The only orm i can use is typeorm and i dont want to use it

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can copy and paste into our IDEs to get to work on your issue. Right now you have a lot of undeclared types and uninitialized properties and it makes it hard to get started.  If you make a nice toy example then we can build off it to show you possible solutions.

Some classic (but nebulous) solutions are 1. extract 'code to store text question' outside of repository class in a way associated to TextQuestion (somehow injected in later), or 2. make 'code to store text question' and 'code to store choice question' into a single piece of code - any place that needs information specific to the type of question, make a Question method that the repository code can call. For example, could the repository ask the question to serialize itself so that the repository class can store a common (but opaque) type, e.g. a JSON string.

Why can't you just use the parent type Question to store all types of questions? That would be the OOP way.

not every question has a isMultiple or not every question has answerOptions so i cant put all in 1 question type

I'm still waiting for a [mre]. Right now all you'll get is untestable suggestions because it's effectively pseudocode (e.g., switch (instanceof).

I think a solution to your problem is to use a more object-oriented way: keep the logic of saving surveys and questions inside the objects and do not use the repository.
interface Question {
    save(): void;
}

class TextQuestion implements Question {
    // constructors and fields
    save() {
        // logic to save TextQuestion to DB
    }
}

class ChoiceQuestion implements Question {
    // constructors and fields
    save() {
        // logic to save ChoiceQuestion to DB
    }
}

class Survey {
    // constructors and fields

    private readonly questions: Question[];

    save(): void {
        // logic to save data of the Survey to DB

        for (let question of this.questions) {
            question.save();
        }
    }
}

// Usage
let cq1 = new ChoiceQuestion(/* some parameters */);
let cq2 = new ChoiceQuestion(/* some parameters */);
let tq1 = new TextQuestion(/* some parameters */);

let survey = new Survey(/* some parameters and questions: cq1, cq2, tq1 */);
survey.save();

P.S. Now you can add new classes of questions without touching ChoiceQuestion, TextQuestion and Survey, thus without violating the Open–closed principle.

This is an inversion of control though. A business object should not care how it is saved; it might even need to be saved in different ways on different media.

@Bergi in my humble opinion on the question: Survey, Question, TextQuestion, ChoiceQuestion are data structures, not objects (or objects which violate a fundamental concept in OOP - encapsulation). If we need to save our questions into file, db, etc., we can create DbTextQuestion, FileTextQuestion, etc. without violating the Open-closed principle (as I understand it is main problem).

Yes, sure, you can make them objects. But my assumption would be that a Question object deals with delivering options to select or being answered, that is what should be its concerns. My point is that in best-practice architecture, the Question object should not depend on a concrete storage layer.

@Bergi, of cause, in a real application you will have a few actors for write questions and give answers. In order not to violate The Interface Segregation Principle, you will have to create several interfaces, for example: SavableQuestion, AnswerableQuestion with different concerns. But in my answer I try to simplify solution to make an accent on the problem (not violate OCP).
